# Bulk DELETE on SQL Server 2008 (Is there anything like Bulk Copy (bcp) for delete data?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any solution for bulk delete in SQL Server?

I can't use TRUNCATE because I want to use WHERE for limiting the rows in action.

Is there anything like Bulk Copy (bcp) for delete data?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No.

You want a DELETE with a WHERE clause: this is standard SQL.

What you can do is batch deletes like this:

```
SELECT 'Starting' --sets @@ROWCOUNT
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
    DELETE TOP (xxx) MyTable WHERE ...
```

Or if you want to remove a very high percentage of rows...

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... INTO #Holdingtable
           FROM MyTable WHERE ..opposite condition..
TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable
INSERT MyTable (col1, col2, ...)
           SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM #Holdingtable
```

Comment: And if it's a lot of transactions, depending on your backup model and log size, do more log backups to free up space in the log...

Comment: Holding data in temporary tables will make you pay more memory usage.

Comment: @Allan Chua: Can you prove that temp tables are held only in memory?

Comment: Ouch...learned the hard way...2h deleting on a batch when I could just apply this approach

Comment: You should also make sure recovery model is `BULK_LOGGED` or `SIMPLE` and use `WITH TABLOCK` to lock the table for the second INSERT, otherwise the transaction log will still be huge. See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20651.sql-server-delete-a-huge-amount-of-data-from-a-table.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can do a couple of things if you want to delete part of your table and not `TRUNCATE` it.

you could select a part of the table into a new table, then switch the two, like so:

```
SELECT *
INTO tmp_MyTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE Key='Value'

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_rename MyTable, old_MyTable, NULL
    EXEC sp_rename tmp_MyTable, MyTable, NULL
    TRUNCATE old_MyTable 
END
```

Secondly, if you're using Partitioning, you can create an identical (empty) table on the same partition scheme.. and if the table is partitioned according to your archiving / purging logic, you can move one partition block from your main table to the new table and then truncate the new table..  For example:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
SWITCH PARTITION 15 TO purge_MyTable PARTITION 2 
GO; 

TRUNCATE TABLE purge_MyTable
```

Ps. 
Partitions are available in SQL 2005/08 Ent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: good answer. FYI, you can use ALTER TABLE..SWITCH without partitioning too, but then you need 2 discrete tables.

Comment: +1 Using the temp table is likely to get fastest results when deleting lots of rows. If the goal is to reclaim the space, I would also run `DBCC SHRINKFILE` for all db files at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

check this

1. article from MSDN [Delete_a_Huge_Amount_of_Data_from](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20651.sql-server-delete-a-huge-amount-of-data-from-a-table.aspx)
2. Information on [Recovery Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx)
3. and [View or Change the Recovery Model of a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189272.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sychare Jedko,

The advantage of TRUNCATE is to avoid logging every single delete in the log file.  a TRUNCATE statement will create a single entry (in log) for the entire batch.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar issue working on a staging table that had issues scaling with proper locks.

Since the relevant table is only referenced in one location for us, we simply replaced that reference with a query for the dynamic table name, which is created with a "select into" similar to what gbn suggested.

This is maintainable because the staging table is only referenced in one place in code, and the expense of the extra database call along with table creation is justified in a warehousing context.  If you have only a few hundred records or reference the table in your code numerous times, then this approach may not work.

Answer (score 0):

When handling million of rows I prefer having a WHERE statement and using SELECT INTO a copy table, delete the original table and rename the copy (back to original name).

Though, you should have stuff like (FK)keys, constraints etc in mind. But using this method you avoid badazz-size of log, and you avoid a huge time consumption of deleting in chunks.

/Snedker

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to delete by chunks:

Here was my solution to delete 100 records at every time:

```
DECLARE @Rows INT
SET @Rows = 1

WHILE (@Rows > 0)
BEGIN
   
     with ToDelete(EMailNotificationID)
         as
         (
         select top 100 q.EMailNotificationID from email
         )

         delete from ToDelete


    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```