# SQLDatareader via CLR not returning SQL Message right way

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, clr

I execute the following code via CLR, is there a reason why the message is not printed to the SQL Server, does it need to wait until the Stored Procedure returns all the rows (there is about 7 Billion rows to return)

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "spCommand_Select_Rows_For_Delete";
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 41600;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            string strSQL = "";
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Started working with ProductTable");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                strSQL = "DELETE FROM ProductTable WHERE ProductId = " + reader["ProductId"].ToString();

                SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);

                cmdDelete.Connection = conn;
                cmdDelete.CommandTimeout = 20800;
                cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Completed working with ProductTable");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM ProductTable
    WHERE ProductInfoId IN
    (
    SELECT ProductInfoId from DeletedProducts
    )
```

Comment: 7 Billion rows from the stored procedure? So you're deleting 7 billion rows from a larger rows ***one by one***?

Comment: Wow that's why there's an A in RBAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you delete 7 billion rows using a nice set based operation. You don't <strike>abuse</strike> iterate through a datareader in CLR.

```
 SELECT 'Starting'
 WHILE ROWCOUNT <> 0
    DELETE TOP (1000000) P
    FROM  ProductTable P
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * from DeletedProducts DP WHERE P.ProductInfoId = DP.ProductInfoId
    )
```

For more, see this question [Bulk DELETE on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126434/bulk-delete-on-sql-server-2008-is-there-anything-like-bulk-copy-bcp-for-delete/2126482#2126482)

But to answer your question, yes, SQL Server will not [PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) (which is what you're doing) immediately

Comment: Will this break out of the table as soon as it hits the top (1000000) instead of continuing to scan the whole table?

Comment: @RPS: It will delete in batches of 1000000 because of WHILE (now I fixed the typo)

Comment: Will this not cause the SQL LOG to grow extremely large?

Comment: Delete 7 billion rows 1 by 1, or in 7000 batches is irrelevant pretty much

Comment: I want delete many rows, but i dont want to eat a lot of disk space and also not take weeks to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend with [RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1660) to do what you want about the message.

But I'm with gbn's answer about not needing the CLR for batched deletes.