# Removal of 30-40 millions record without affecting performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, large-data-volumes

I have a SQL Server database running in Full recovery.  I need to remove data (around 30-40 million records) but I cannot take the database offline as it's in constant use.  I also cannot switch it to Simple recovery mode incase anything happens and we lose live data.  When I try to remove the data in small chunks (around 2 million rows), the transaction log becomes extremely large and causes the process to become extremely slow.  Due to back-up jobs running at night, I only have a small timeframe.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can do this?  I thought about copying the table into another database (in Simple recovery mode) and then remove the data.  Is this a good idea?

There are 3 tables in question.  Campaign, Events and Targets.  Its the Events table that has the millions of records in and this is what takes the time to delete.  The all have the necessary relations via Id columns.

Comment: have you tried smaller chunks?

Comment: Unfortunately, these "chunks" are as small as I can get them.

Comment: how many rows will be left after the removal?

Comment: As with most database questions, you should include the schema and, in this case, the distribution of data across the key fields. You state that "these 'chunks' are as small as I can get them" but we don't _know_ that with the information given.

Comment: @Mat: Around 50-55 million rows will be left.

Comment: Are you using the enterprice edition

Comment: @Ian: Yes, Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *have* to use small chunks otherwise your transaction log will increases

Every one one of 30-40 million deletes will be logged. If you create a new table and copy "to keep" rows you'll still have 50+ million logged rows. The fact of simple vs full recovery doesn't matter: each delete/insert is logged

If the log increases in simple recovery then I suspect you are doing it in a transaction. So the 30-40 million deletes are still logged, even in simple recovery because it would all have to be rolled back perhaps.

For 40 x 1 million deletes without a transaction in simpler recovery you can use [CHECKPOINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188748.aspx) to assist in log tidy up

See [Bulk DELETE on SQL Server 2008 (Is there anything like Bulk Copy (bcp) for delete data?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126434/bulk-delete-on-sql-server-2008-is-there-anything-like-bulk-copy-bcp-for-delete/2126482#2126482) for more

But something like:

```
SELECT 'Starting' --sets @@ROWCOUNT
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
    CHECKPOINT
    --Edit: must be last to set @@ROWCOUNT
    DELETE TOP (1000000) MyTable WHERE ...
END
```

Process:

- full backup
- change recovery to simple
- delete
- change recovery to full (or what it was before)
- full backup

You don't have many other options if you insist on deleting 30+ million rows in one go in a short windows...

Comment: @gbn: This is great information.  I'm not deleting 30-40 million records in one go, it is just the small 1-2 million chunks per campaign, but the total is 30-40 million rows.

Comment: @gbn: If I use `CHECKPOINT` and cancel the query, will this still `commit` those records or will they be rolled back?

Comment: neither: it will rollback only those rows in the current delete batch. Any rows already deleted will stay deleted. CHECKPOINT is only used to trigger a log tidy up

Comment: @gbn: In the `WHILE` loop, will this update the `@@ROWCOUNT` after each iteration?

Comment: @gbn: As I'm using `CHECKPOINT`, does this remove the need for a `transaction` wrapped around the `while` loop?

Comment: @Neil Knight: unrelated. CHECKPOINT triggers a t-log tidy up in simple recovery. Using a transaction will put you back to huge t-log again and there is no need to batch: you'll still have a 30m+ row delete in the log that could be rolled back. And CHECKPOINT will have *no effect* if 1. not in simple 2. you use a transaction

Answer (score 1):

What criteria do you use to select the 30-40 millions rows for deletion? If it is something fairly straightforward (such as 'older than 10 days') then you may be able to use SQL Server's table partitioning mechanism. There are some well-documented techniques (see link below) on partition switching to deal with use-cases similar to yours.

pjjH

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.100%29.aspx