# SQL Delete TOP statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

my table (sql sever 2000) contains large amount of rows, when i delete row, it extremely slow.

i saw some post/forum that suggest to use a WHILE loop function to delete record by batch.

my sql is:

```
DELETE FROM Tprs_master where Fincmonth='201109';
```

I had rewrite to:

```
DELETE FROM(SELECT TOP 100 FROM tprs_master) AS t1 WHERE t1.Fincmonth='201109'
```

but it doesn't work.

how can I rewrite the above sql to DELETE TOP style ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSDN DELETE page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) gives examples and syntax

```
DELETE TOP (100) FROM Tprs_master where Fincmonth='201109';
```

Note: SQL Server 2005+ only

Also see for more examples [Bulk DELETE on SQL Server 2008 (Is there anything like Bulk Copy (bcp) for delete data?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126434/bulk-delete-on-sql-server-2008-is-there-anything-like-bulk-copy-bcp-for-delet/2126482#2126482)

Edit: OP has SQL Server 2000

```
SET ROWCOUNT 100
DELETE FROM Tprs_master where Fincmonth='201109';
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: SET ROWCOUNT for SQL Server 2000: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: @DavidEG: I didn't mention it has side effects because it limits intermediate results too which can be confusing. Should be OK with a simple DELETE though. And SQL Server 2000 is ancient history now :)

Comment: @Joe Yan: which version of SQL Server please?

Comment: @Joe Yan: answer was updated: I guessed SQL Server 2000. You asked questions about SQL Server 2008 earlier: are you running a mixed environment?