# Delete number of rows from table Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In general it's necessary to delete about 110K rows from table `Nodes` but their id are not declared explicitly but are given from another table.

```
DECLARE @gh Table(id int);
INSERT INTO @gh (id) SELECT node_id FROM Relations;
DELETE FROM Nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh)
```

Selection (`SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh`) contains about 20K rows and server couldn't delete them due to expired timeout. What other ways to do it are there?

Comment: Can you add the XML execution plan please (estimated will do, or use `DELETE TOP (10) FROM Nodes ...`)

Answer (score 3):

If you're keeping 20k of 130k, I'd do it a different way

```
SELECT N.* 
  INTO #NodesTemp 
FROM  
  Relations R JOIN Nodes N ON R.id = N.id;

TRUNCATE TABLE Nodes;

INSERT Nodes SELECT * FROM #NodesTemp;

DROP TABLE #NodesTemp;
```

Edit:

- do you have a DELETE trigger on Nodes?
- do you have foreign keys to Nodes that need checked?

Comment: The `Nodes` and `Relations` have a `1:n` relationship. Will not this result in rows duplication in the `Nodes` table?

Comment: This also won't work if there are foreign keys to the Nodes table.

Comment: @ypercube: possibly, but a DISTINCT will fix that. I was going for a concept, not runnable code

Comment: @Serguei: true, but you could then [DELETE in batches with no JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126482/27535) or rename tables etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help. It will delete all Nodes where there is not a related Relation entry. The outer join should be much faster than using a "not in" clause with the sub query.

```
delete n
from Nodes n left outer join Relations r on n.id = r.node_id
where r.node_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the nodes in batches instead of all at once by adding a TOP clause to DELETE:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh))
DELETE TOP (100) Nodes
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh)
```

Comment: thanks, it seems to work but has appeared another problem with unsufficient memory amount (mashine has 4GB).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `DINSTINCT` for this. It adds unnecessary overhead to the delete statement.

Second, why are you using a temporary table? Have you tried to combine these 2 statements into one?:

```
DELETE 
FROM Nodes 
WHERE id NOT IN 
      (SELECT node_id FROM Relations)
```

or delete the rows in smaller chunks, like @Serguei suggested:

```
SELECT 1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1000)
    FROM Nodes 
    WHERE id NOT IN 
          (SELECT node_id FROM Relations)
END
```

Comment: all the same timeout exception

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `Relations.node_id` and `Nodes.id` ?