# Batch delete data from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-delete

How I can delete data from SQL Server table using batch.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126434/bulk-delete-on-sql-server-2008-is-there-anything-like-bulk-copy-bcp-for-delet

Comment: batch is just a group of statement e.g. stored procedure

Comment: Do you mean via a batch file i.e command line sql?

Comment: sqlcmd bol:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean configuring your sql script as batch job? if yes, then write your sql query in a script like

```
Filename: sqldelete.sql

delete from my_table where <some condition>;
GO
```

Create a batch file `.bat` and call your sql script in there like

```
sqlcmd -s <server name> -d <db name> -i sqldelete.sql
```

For more options on `sqlcmd`: run command `sqlcmd /?` in command prompt

Configure this `.bat` file to run in schedule as per your need

If you want to know how to schedule task in windows task scheduler then take a look @ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569 (This is for WINXP).