# SQL Server 2012 Stored Procedure timing out. How to fix it?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008-x64

Context: SQL Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit), 2 cores, lots of RAM and HD space,
         ADODB via JScript (not .NET)

These really simple stored procedures keep timing out. It's not like I have a lot of records either (from a server point of view): 100,000 or so.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Transfer_Part1]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Primary.dbo.Post
    SELECT *
    FROM Secondary.dbo.Pre
    WHERE HrefProcessed = (-1)
        AND ReferrerProcessed = (-1);

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Transfer_Part3]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE
    FROM Secondary.dbo.Pre
    WHERE HrefProcessed = (-1)
        AND ReferrerProcessed = (-1);
```

Is there anything I can do to stop getting these messages?

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Query timeout expired
EXEC Transfer_Part1
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Query timeout expired
EXEC Transfer_Part3
```

Comment: Do you have an 2-column index on HrefProcessed and ReferrerProcessed? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126482/27535 for the second one. ANd please add the query plans and table structures

Comment: Do now! Please make your comment into an answer and I'll give you the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an 2-column index on HrefProcessed and ReferrerProcessed?

Also see [Bulk DELETE on SQL Server 2008 (Is there anything like Bulk Copy (bcp) for delete data?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126434/bulk-delete-on-sql-server-2008-is-there-anything-like-bulk-copy-bcp-for-delet/2126482#2126482) for the second one.