# Should i disable clustered index before deleting data?

Tags: sql-server

i know this has been discussed already like anything but could not find a reliable answer i can go with.

Suppose i have a table with 10 billion records and need to delete records with identity column in where clause. which option should i go with?

option 1: disable the index which will save overhead to rearrange the index after deletion but will take longer time to search which row needs to deleted.

option 2: will not do anything with index which will locate the row very fast but rearrange the index can take some time.

i am more inclined towards the 2 option but want to see what will experts say? :)

Comment: Thanks Martin for Prompt reply and sorry to give huge data size for my example but all i want is to understand logic, will it be the same if table has only thousands rows where row can be identified in a heap

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2126434/27535 It depends on if you deleting a few rows or billions

Comment: If you disabled a table's clustered index, it disables access to the table; you can, however, disable nonclustered indexes and carry out deletes, then re-enable them (via `REBUILD`) which is often more performant during large deletes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Suppose i have a table with 10 billion records and need to delete records with identity column in where clause. which option should i go with?

If you're deleting (or inserting) more than 10% of the table (1 billion records), you should remove all of the **non-clustering** indexes, delete the records, then rebuild the **non-clustering** indexes.

If you're deleting less than 10% of the table, leave the indexes in place.

You're free to do performance testing to see if the 10% rule applies to your SQL Server database engine.

Comment: Thanks for giving this 10% border Gilbert

Comment: Do you mean "you should disable" instead of "you should remove"?

Comment: @Andrei Sura:  Nope.  I mean remove or delete.  You have to rebuild the indexes after you're finished deleting or inserting rows.

Comment: What about high DTU usage when rebuilding the indexes?

Comment: @Enrico: You'll have the high DTU usage updating all the indexes as you delete.  As always, perform measurements of your particular database system to determine what method works best when deleting massive numbers of rows.

Answer (score 9):

"Option 1" is not an option anyway.

Disabling the **clustered** index will make the whole table inaccessible and you would not be able to run a `DELETE` on the table anyway. It would fail with

> The query processor is unable to produce a plan because the index ...
>   is disabled.

Example code generating this error.

```
CREATE TABLE T(X INT CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Y INT);

ALTER INDEX PK ON T DISABLE

DELETE FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally delete indexes for any bulk inserts into the tables, that too for temporary duration. Once the bulk insert is done, the indexes are created back.

Indexes would help locate the record easily for update/delete operations and you would never want to remove them in such cases.

HTH.