# BCP and indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I am attempting to import data via BCP. I disabled the sole index on a table to enable BCP to import quickly. When I import with the index enabled, it takes too long. When I disable the index, somewhere in the import it throws an error complaining the index is disabled:

```
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8655
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The query processo
r is unable to produce a plan because the index 'xxxxxxxx' on table
or view 'yyyyyyyyyyy' is disabled.

BCP copy in failed
```

What are the best practices around indexes and BCP? Suggestions?

Comment: This probably answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16942693/243925

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I did not really track it down. I had to completely remove the index to get the import working. I do not yet understand why you cannot just disable and then re-enable it.

Comment: I found another question about ["disabling clustered indexes" on the Database Administrators site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/why-disabling-a-clustered-index-makes-the-table-inaccessible), the selected answer is quite detailed.